# Minimizing $\int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^2 \, dx$ with constraints

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

> **Problem.** Given that $f \in C^{(1)} [0,1]$, $f(0) = a$, $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = 0$, find minimum value of $\int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^2 \, dx$.

I've tried applying Cauchy-Schwarz, but only got the lower bound of $a^2$. I also could construct an example where the value is $4a^2$, but couldn't make any progress after that.

**My Attempt.** With Cauchy we have

$$ \left| \int_{0}^{c} f(x) g(x) \, dx \right|^2
\leq \left( \int_{0}^{c} f^2(x) \, dx \right) \left( \int_{0}^{c} g^2(x) \, dx \right), $$

where we can substitute $f(x) = f'(x)$, $g(x) = 1$, so:

$$ \left| \int_{0}^{c} f'(x) \, dx \right|^2 \leq \int_{0}^{c} f'^2(x) \, dx. $$

For some $c$ in $[0,1]$ we have $f(c) \leq 0$, so we can choose $c$ such that left side is at least $(f(c) - f(0))^2 = a^2$. The right part doesn't decrease while increasing $c$, so that's why the lower bound is $a^2$. $a^2$ can also be the answer, but I couldn't find such an example.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why don't you outline what you did with Cauchy-Schwarz? How do you know $a^2$ isn't the correct answer?

Comment: Fixed this in last edit

Comment: Your bound is generally loose since $\min f<0$ and $\max f>0$ (when $a\neq0$), and thus $|f(c)-f(0)|$ can be chosen to be greater than $|a|$. Instead, consider $(x-1)f'(x)$, whose integral over $[0,1]$ is a constant. Apply C-S inequality to it, and you will get the answer. Moreover, the minimum is attained when $f$ is a quadratic function.

Comment: Following the advice of the above comment, the minimum is achieved by $f(x)=a (1 - 3x + \frac{3}{2} x^2)$ with the minimum value of $3a^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{ f \in C^1[0, 1] : f(0) = a \text{ and } \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0 \}$. Also, write $Df = f'(x)$ and note that $D$ is a linear map from $C^1[0, 1]$ to $C^0[0, 1]$. Consequently,

$$ \min_{f \in \mathcal{A}} \int_{0}^{1} f'(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
= \min_{g \in D(\mathcal{A})} \int_{0}^{1} g(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Now, for $f \in \mathcal{A}$ we have

$$ 0
= \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \underbrace{f(0)}_{=a} + \int_{0}^{1} (1 - x) f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Using this, it is not hard to verify that $g \in D(\mathcal{A})$ if and only if $\int_{0}^{1} (1 - x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = -a$. Now, by the
Cauchy–Schwarz inequality,

$$ a^2 = \left( \int_{0}^{1} (1 - x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^2 \leq \left( \int_{0}^{1} (1 - x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( \int_{0}^{1} g(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \right) $$

with the equality iff $g(x) \propto (1 - x)$. Moreover, this condition is compatible with the constraint $g \in D(\mathcal{A})$, in the sense that there exists $g$ satisfying both constraints simultaneously. Consequently,

$$ \min_{g \in D(\mathcal{A})} \int_{0}^{1} g(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{a^2}{\int_{0}^{1} (1 - x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}
= 3a^2. $$